# ruby version error when pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, heroku-postgres, heroku-toolbelt

I am running into an error when trying to push my app to Heroku. I have pasted my gemfile below for your reference.

The Error:

An error occurred while installing ruby-2.3.1 remote:  !      remote:  !     This version of Ruby is not available on Heroku-18.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby "~> 2.3.1"

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'bootstrap', '>=4.0'
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a list of Ruby versions currently supported on Heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions

You'll have to upgrade your application to at least Ruby 2.4.5 to get it working there.

Comment: yea that is what I am gathering but I am running ubuntu and am not sure how to upgrade to a ruby -v 4 on Ubuntu

Comment: I recommend using something like [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to install the newer version instead of using your OS distribution package manager. Then bump the referenced runtime in your `Gemfile` and try running your testsuite in your updated bundle. Usually this should "just work" and foreseeing any possible issues is out of scope for a SO answer ;)

Comment: ok great i used RVM and got ruby upgraded to 2.6 thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 11):

heroku stack:set heroku-16, running this command in your terminal will help you.

Comment: HEROOOOOOOOOOOO

Answer (score 2):

Change the Heroku Stack for Ruby -v 2.6.2
I used the following command to fix it.

```
heroku stack:set heroku-16
```

Reference: [upokary.com](https://upokary.com/the-ruby-version-you-are-trying-to-install-does-not-exist-on-this-stack/)