# How to use Ruby preview releases with Bundler and keep deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundler

In a project using bundler and Heroku I want to test the ruby-3.3.0-preview1 release, I can make bundler work with the preview version locally, but can't deploy it to Heroku, and the instructions from Heroku docs doesn't work locally.

I can install the ruby version (I'm using rbenv) and set the version to be used with my .ruby-version file set to `3.3.0-preview1` (or if I want I can call it just 3.3.0 using rbenv-alias plugin, but this also will not solve the problem).

I can use the preview version in the Gemfile by specifying it with a different, but similar, name:

```
ruby '3.3.0preview1'
```

It works as expected, locally, install all gems inside the new version and the RUBY_VERSION can be confirmed to be 3.3.0 inside the application.

But, Heroku doesn't accept this version, it raises the error:

```
The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist: ruby-3.3.0.preview1
```

and the [Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2591) suggests to put 3.3.0 in the Gemfile, but this actually doesn't work also, because if I use just 3.3.0, bundler don't run locally, it says:

```
Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.preview1, but your Gemfile specified 3.3.0
```

Obs.: I also tried to specify the preview1 as the patchlevel in the Gemfile, but this doesn't work either:

```
ruby '3.3.0', patchlevel: 'preview1'
```

**[Update]** For reference, I created an issue in the heroku-buildpack repository, because this seems to be a bug:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/1387

Comment: What is your Heroku stack? Just check it in the console with `heroku stack`.

Comment: The stack is heroku-22

Answer (score 1):

This answer became more of a checklist to go over when debugging the issue mentioned by OP, so I left this to the future reader (myself included) as a note.

#### First

You might need to change your Heroku stack.

And you can check yours with

```
heroku stack
```

Verify that you are using the latest one (heroku-22), usually, it has [support for the newer Ruby versions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#unsupported-ruby-versions) and it says to use 3.3.0 in your Gemfile for `3.3.0-preview1`.

In case it is not `heroku-22` you will need to set it with:

```
heroku stack:set heroku-22
```

Be aware that upgrading to the latest stack has its [flow and some implications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-to-the-latest-stack).

And `3.3.0-preview1` has been available since [May, 12th](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2591)

A similar question and some answers on SO:

- [ruby version error when pushing to heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062378/ruby-version-error-when-pushing-to-heroku)

#### Second

I noticed that the error message references: `ruby-3.3.0.preview1` where it is odd to have `.preview1` there. Could it be a typo where you should have `ruby 3.3.0-preview1` referenced in your Gemfile?

#### Third

This link could be helpful with [specifying Ruby version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions#ruby-version-specifiers) as there might be an issue between the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock.

#### Fourth

Buildpack shenanigans. As said in one of the comments, Heroku updated a Ruby buildpack to use `ruby "3.3.0"` in Gemfile to check the `preview1`.
It is also possible to lock the buildpack to a specific version like so:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git#v254
```

The latest version is `v256` but the `3.3.0-preview1` version was included in `v254`.
It might prove useful to check/select different versions of the buildpack.

Comment: The stack of this project is already the heroku-22 and the error is that it is not possible to use 3.3.0 in the Gemfile and use the preview version, as I already said in the question

(...) if I use just 3.3.0, bundler don't run locally, it says:


> Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.preview1, but your Gemfile specified 3.3.0

Comment: I updated this answer. Included an observation of your posting. @EvertonJ.Carpes

Comment: I also considered this, but it was not the case.
I used "-" but the message appears with ".", I don't know why

Comment: Ok, there is one more thing to try. Updated the answer again.

Comment: I will double-check the thing about . vs -

Comment: Actually, to make bundler work with preview1 locally I needed to use:

ruby '3.3.0preview1'

without . or -

If I use -, it doesn't understand it, it presents the error:


Your Ruby version is 3.3.0.preview1, but your Gemfile specified 3.3.0.pre.preview1

Comment: They definitely changed the buildpack to use "ruby 3.3.0" in the Gemfile. Link: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/commit/6a9a81ad880359df509b2ef499fbe19d82f70f86

Comment: Thanks for finding the buildpack reference; I think this seems to be a bug, so I will open an issue there!

Comment: Sure thing, I hope it will help. Yet again, I edited the answer to mention the buildpack shenanigans.